# Save dynamic variables in text file without closing it using C#

Tags: c#, file, overwrite

I need to save six dynamic variables in a text file as fast as possible in a way that if the power is turned off (or application is killed), I can have access to the last saved version of the variables all together (not just some of the variables).

Writing these six variables in registry takes `~0.1 ms` which is good. However I'd rather avoid modifying the registry.

I tried `StreamWriter` like this in a backgroundworker loop:

```
System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("test.txt", false);
file.Write("Comma Separated Version of Variables in String");
file.Flush();
file.Close();
```

It takes more that `1 ms` which is slow for my application! So, I removed first and last line out of the loop:

```
System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("test.txt", false);
while (true)
{  
   file.Write("Comma Separated Version of Variables in String");
   file.Flush();
}
file.Close();
```

It is now excellent (`~0.007 ms`)! However, it appends the new strings to the file. How I can overwrite the first line of the text file (it has only one line) without closing  it?

EDIT: I also tried `WriteAllText`which works but it is like `15` times slower that the above code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set position of the stream to 0.

```
while (true)
{
    file.BaseStream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
    file.WriteLine("Comma Separated Version of Variables in String");
    file.Flush();
}
```